# How can I totally remove mongodb?

Tags: ubuntu-mate

I used the following to remove all mongodb packages so I can start fresh, but it does not seem to be working.  How can I totally remove mongodb?

I did:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove mongodb-*
sudo apt-get purge mongodb mongodb-clients mongodb-server mongodb-dev
```

None of all that works.  When I do `mongod --version` I still get:

```
db version v2.6.10
2017-10-01T00:20:56.172-0400 git version: nogitversion
2017-10-01T00:20:56.172-0400 OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
```

When I run `dpkg -S $(which mongod)` I get the following:

```
mongodb-server: /usr/bin/mongod
```

The same for `mongo`.

Comment: 1. "autoremove" is run "as is", without arguments, and is not for uninstalling software, just clean up old kernels and orphaned packages. 2. `sudo apt-get purge mongodb*` should work if and only if `mongodb` was installed with apt. Was it?

Comment: I get this error when I run that: dpkg-query: error: --search needs at least one file name pattern argument

Comment: There was a typo so I ran this: dpkg -S $(which mongod)
 and got the following: mongodb-server: /usr/bin/mongod

Comment: I think I finally got it removed.  Thanks Kaz. Your snippet pointed me to where to look and then I ran sudo apt-get purge mongodb-server.  I still don't see why my original command did not do the same thing though.

Comment: If you got your issue solved please add an answer below with the necessary command(s) and accept by clicking the tick next to it.